# Find & Replace value if "AR" found in a column

Tags: excel, vba

Good Morning everyone

I hope someone can help me to write a VBA code.

What I am trying to achieve is that when in column C is found with AR then all the cells in the column that contain S & s to replace with C.

and continue doing so

Thank you

Comment: Did you try doing that manually and recording your actions?

Comment: Hi @Dominique no as i am not that great on excel. i someone has written me an code to send an email based on a certain value however now i would like to reset the value back to zero if ar is found with the range cell column C

Comment: I have got this formula and it works however it only works 1 time and not continue repeating "=IF(COUNTIF(B11:AF33,"ar")<>0,0,SUMPRODUCT(LEN(B11:AF33)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B11:AF33,"S",""))))"

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MyMacro ()

Dim Cell As Range

Columns("C:C").Select
Set cell = Selection.Find(What:="AR", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas,_
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If cell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Did not found AR"

Else
    Columns("C:C").Replace    What:="S", _
                            Replacement:="C", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False
    Columns("C:C").Replace    What:="s", _
                            Replacement:="C", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for for putting the code together however get an error on the link "Columns ("C:C").select" error code Run-time error 1004 Select method of range class failed

Comment: Hi @trada i have tried your suggestion and nothing happens, it does not changes any S to C when AR is found